# QML - How to regenerate GridView dynamically?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

I have a `GridView` and that's first model is 6 and delegate of `GridView` is `Rectangle`. When I click the `Rectangle`, visible of `Rectangle` is `false`. When visibles of all rectangles are false, I'm opening a window and there is a button in window. When I click the button, that button changes model of `GridView` and window closes. But `GridView` doesn't regenerate. How can I regenerate `GridView` with that's new model? If I load `GridView` with `Loader`, so old `GridView` doesn't delete and new `GridView` is loading on old `GridView`. How can I solve this problem?

**Edit!**
I'm writing an example.
I have a `GridView`:
**MyGrid.qml:**

```
GridView {
  id: gridView
  model: 2
  delegate: Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 70
    height: 70
    MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: rect.visible = false }
  }
}
```

`model` of `GridView` is 2 at the moment. I have this QML file:
**MyPopup.qml:**

```
Popup {
  id: popup
  background: Rectangle {
    width: 250
    height: 250
    color: 'red'
    Button {
      id: btn
      onClicked: {
        gridView.model = gridView.model * 2; // I changed model
        popup.close(); // Then I closed popup
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This popup is opening if visibles of all rectangles are `false`.
I changed model of GridView but when popup closed, I can't see any on the screen. Because there is still GridView with its old model (and you remember, visibles of rectangles are `false`).
I want when `model` of `GridView` changed, I saw new `GridView` with its new model. How can I do it?

Comment: No this is not my answer. I want to dynamically create and destroy GridView

Comment: I edited my question, I added the example.

Comment: There is something else wrong with your code, when the model is changed, the view will recreate all delegates.